# Robot Framework with excel xlsx Getting exceptions "ValueError: Argument 'col_num' got value 'data' that cannot be converted to integer."

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

Trying to incorporate excel.xlsx into Robot Framework, but getting exceptions: "ValueError: Argument 'col_num' got value 'data' that cannot be converted to integer." Please help!!

The code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ExcelLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem    
Library    robot.api.logger  

*** Variables ***
${sFileName}      ${EXECDIR}\\TestData\\TestSheet.xlsx    # DataSheet

*** Test Cases ***
TC_01_Taking URL from Excel
    Open given Excel file    ${sFileName}
    #Fetch the data from Excel for given Test Case and Column Name    \    SheetName    Row    Column
    ${sURL}    Get data from Excel with given column    data    TC_02    Browser
    Log    ${sURL}
        
*** Keywords ***
Open given Excel file
    [Arguments]    ${sFileName}
    #Check that the given Excel Exists
    ${inputfileStatus}    ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    OperatingSystem.File Should Exist    ${sFileName}
    Run Keyword If    "${inputfileStatus}"=="PASS"    info    ${sFileName} Test data file exist    ELSE    Fail    Cannot locate the given Excel file.
    Open Excel File    ${sFileName}
        
Get data from Excel with given column
    [Arguments]    ${sSheetName}    ${sTestCaseNo}    ${sColumnName}
    log    ${sColumnName}
    **${colCount}    Read Excel Column    ${sSheetName}**#Fails here
    FOR    ${y}    IN RANGE    0    ${colCount}
        ${header}    Read Excel Cell    ${sSheetName}    ${y}    0
        #Check if this is the given header
        Run Keyword If    "${header}"=="${sColumnName}"    Set Test Variable    ${colNum}    ${y}
    END    
    log    ${colNum}
    #Get the total rows in the Sheet
    ${iTotalRows}    ExcelLibrary.Read Excel Row    ${sSheetName}
    FOR    ${iRowNo}    IN RANGE    1    ${iTotalRows}+1
        ${TC_Num}    Read Excel Cell    ${sSheetName}    0    ${iRowNo}
        #Incase TestCase No is same , fetch the data from same row and given column No
        ${sSearchedData}    Run Keyword If    "${sTestCaseNo}"=="${TC_Num}"    ExcelLibrary.Read Excel Cell    ${sSheetName}    ${colNum}
        ...    ${iRowNo}
        Run Keyword If    "${sTestCaseNo}"=="${TC_Num}"    Exit For Loop
    END    
    [Return]    ${sSearchedData}
```

Also, here is the python keyword inside library ExcelLibrary.py:

```
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterator, List, Optional, Tuple

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet

def read_excel_column(self, col_num: int, row_offset: int = 0, max_num: int = 0,
                          sheet_name: str = None) -> List[Any]:

col_num = int(col_num)
        row_offset = int(row_offset)
        max_num = int(max_num)
        sheet = self.get_sheet(sheet_name)
        row_iter: Iterator[Tuple[Cell]] = sheet.iter_rows(min_col=col_num, max_col=col_num,
                                                          min_row=1 + row_offset,
                                                          max_row=row_offset + max_num)
```

Enclosed is data file 'TestSheet.xlsx'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your method `read_excel_column()` has 4 parameters, all of them with default values (we'll talk about "self" in a bit). When you call it with less than 4 arguments, the interpreter will start passing them in the same order.
This means if you call it with 2 arguments, the first will go to the "col_num" paramter, the second - to "row_offset". Thus when you called it:

```
${colCount}    Read Excel Column    ${sSheetName}
```

, you are actually passing `${sSheetName}` to the "col_num" paramter, and - you get the error the value can't be casted to int.

This is easily solve able - just call the method with named parameters, specifing explicitly which parameter the argument is for:

```
${colCount}    Read Excel Column    1   sheet_name=${sSheetName}
```

So when the python interpreter goes to execute the method, it will pass the value to the right parameter.

---

About "self", why I didn't count it in the number of parameters - because that 1st one is used in class methods, to automatically pass the class instance. The sample code you've given is with `read_excel_column()` being a function - not a method in a class - but I *presume* your actual code is with a class (otherwise, if it really is a standalone function, "self" is just a parameter like any other, would get the value you passed, and would not produce this error).

Comment: Thanks for you valuable answer. I did add up col_num=${sSheetName} but not working getting same error. I did not create python code 'ExcelLibrary.py', but is a library created by robot framework team itself.

Comment: @RN it was a (copy & paste) mistake I did - the actual parameter is "sheet_number", I've edited the answer.

Comment: unfortunately, updated the line sheet_number=${sSheetName}, but not working. On variable '${sSheetName}' I am passing excel sheet name data is setup from test case level. Probably running the code on python editor could provide a clear picture. What do you think?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean - what error is it generating?

Comment: Same exceptions: ValueError: Argument 'col_num' got value '"sheet_number"=data' that cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: You're not passing a column number - the method does read and return you a column, just a sheet name. Call it with `Excel Column    1   sheet_name=${sSheetName}` - the first argument is the number of the column.